# White space at start of encoded json array

Tags: php

Admittedly it has been a while since I have been in the php world, but i'm not sure why I am getting 3 spaces at the start of my `json_encode` string.

```
"   [{"id":"1","display_name":"Bob"}]"
```

This is the php i have:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");

$queryResult = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $queryResult[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($queryResult);
}
```

When I echo `print_r($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`﻿ I get the following:

```
   Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [display_name] => Twitch Dock John
)
```

The 3 spaces are there as well.. what have I done wrong (expecting an incoming face-palm moment)?

Comment: What's the context - where is your `<?php` ?

Comment: as you can tell already, neither PDO nor JSON has nothing to do with your issue. even if you make it `echo 'Hello world';` the spaces would be there

Comment: And now it's time to look for the BOM signature...

Comment: Just try to echo something before your if() , And `echo json_encode($queryResult);` It will help you to check from where this space is coming.

Comment: Work around / patch can be to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php to strip white spaces from the string.

Comment: Update: Thanks for all of the comments guys, it is re-assuring that the consensus is that the PDO is ok. I'm currently looking for additional output (fun) - I'll update if necessary.

Comment: Found the bastards - 3 spaces after my `?>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can possibly figure the spot in your codebase where output starts by determining where HTTP headers have been sent:

```
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    echo "Ouput starts on: $file: $line\n";
}
```

Comment: AS this is probably not an answer to the question it is a very usefull thing to know.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Why not an answer? Since the sole purpose of the script is to emit JSON, any prior output is probably an error.

Comment: This answer way exceeded my expectations for this question. This is incredibly useful!

Comment: it does not fix the error but it will tell you where it is. But again, this is awesome.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Yep. Then comes the difficult part, opening the offending file and hitting **del** ;-P

Comment: maybe consider adding it to the main thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php function `header_sent()`is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier When you get *Headers already sent* the error message already includes the information that `headers_sent()` provides.

Comment: Yes i know, but people without error_logging knowledge does not, here comes the hard part => open the log file ;-)